# "ionic cordova platform add ios" Failed to fetch platform cordova-ios@0.0.1

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

When I run "ionic cordova platform add ios", that got the following error. How to fix it?

```
Exception: Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@0.0.1

    Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-ios@0.0.1
    Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
    Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
    Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    npm ERR! code ETARGET
    npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for cordova-ios@0.0.1
    npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
    npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/thanhnguyen/.npm/_logs/2017-08-25T10_34_19_961Z-debug.log
```

Comment: may be your ionic & cordova not setup correctly . please uninstall and setup again

Comment: @sunielkalwani thank you so much!
I re-install ionic & cordova. I run "ionic cordova platform add ios@latest", this worked again.

Comment: This is wrong. You don't need to uninstall or reinstall anything. Just adding the @latest fixed your issue, not the rest.

Answer (score 7):

The following command should resolve the issue:

> cordova platform add ios@latest

Answer (score 3):

Inside my `package.json` there was a `ios:0.0.1` which I removed and got resolved.